# always return false when compare an existing string from a test file to the newly enterer object with parameter

Tags: java, string, object, methods, string-comparison

This is my method for checking if the first three elements are the same

carModel is a string

purchasePrice is a double

purchaseDate is a Date

I stored these in a txt file, separating with a comma and a space like ", "

However, this method always returns false,even if i input just the same record. But when I changed the first"&&" into "||", it would return true.

```
public static boolean exist(Car c) {
    String line = "";
    File file = new File("Car Records.txt");
    try {
        BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = fr.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] s = line.split(", ");
            if ((s[0].equals(c.carModel)) &&(s[1].equals(c.purchasePrice))&& (s[2].equals(c.purchaseDate))
                    && (s[5].equals(false)) ){
                return true;
            }
        }
        fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: `s[5].equals(false)` - a `String` will never be equal to a `boolean`.

Comment: Perhaps the data type of your variables are not strings ie c.purchasePrice and c.purchaseDate?

Comment: Debug your code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s[0]`,`s[1]` and `s[2]` are `String`s, so comparing them to `double` or to `Date` will never return true.

You'll have to parse the input Strings into the correct type before making the comparison.

You'll need something like this (I didn't fix the `Date` comparison, since I don't know how you represent the date in your input file):

```
        if ((s[0].equals(c.carModel)) &&(Double.parseDouble(s[1])==c.purchasePrice)&& (s[2].equals(c.purchaseDate))
                && (s[5].equals("false")) ){
            return true;
        }
```